# Using z-scores for ML estimation in SEM?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, structural-equation-modeling, standardization, confirmatory-factor

I'm running a series of congeneric models with neuropsychological performance data obtained using different scales (e.g., time, errors etc). These will later be used in an SEM. A weighted factor score will be calculated for each indicator on the latent from the factor score weights.

From what I can gather, z-scoring the raw data prior to estimation is the way to go. However, I've read in a couple of places that maximum likelihood estimation (which I intend to use) assumes unstandardised values. What I can't find is what effect this has on the parameter estimation. Has anyone run with this approach before? Or have any suggestions? I'm also dealing with a limited sample size, so estimation techniques that require large samples are not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Congeneric models are analyzed using the covariance matrix. Standardizing your values turns that covariance matrix into a correlation matrix. Proportionally, the solutions should be the same, but in absolute size of parameter estimates, the values may be different.

To be safe, run a model with the raw scores, and generate the standardized solution. Then, run the model with the z-scores.  If the results are comparable (nearly same standard errors and p-values), then it won't matter which you use.